# How to set up virtual hosts for sites in each user's directory

Tags: apache2

Hi I am looking to set up virtual hosts and I would like to put the files in each user's directory so I have each user and his sites held separately.

So for example john would have in /home/jean/public_html:
www.site1.com
www.site2.com

and tony in home/tony/public_html:
www.site3.com
www.site4.com
www.site5.com

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial for setting this up with Apache? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called "virtual mass hosting", and Apache has [documentation about it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html).